# Remove web content emails and add spam protected content?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have job crawler website, which crawls list 10,000 of jobs in my website, however i have a issue with some job descriptions has direct email link saying

please email your resume to hr@xxx.com . This results in a spam attacks for them, So i need find a solution where i can hide these emails from the spam bots and BUT i need to show them to the valid human user.

I am wondering about the possible solutions and few things comes into my mind are

1. May be doing a preg replace to email and replace email with "click here view email" do some JavaScript script to retrieve the actual email when clicked.
2. Use captcha text to enter and get the email (very inconvenience for the end user)

Any other possible solutions ?

Comment: I would not show email address at all, link to page with a form to send email using a  captcha

Comment: bots generally don't run js, so even a simple `<script>document.write('user'); document.write('@'); document.write('example.com')</script>` would defeat them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spoof with css like :

generated HTML:

```
<span class='eml'>user<p>randomdata</p>@<p>randomdata</p>domain<p>randomdata</p>.com</span>
```

css:

```
.eml p {
   dispay: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HmZew/

other fun thing: you can change text direction (which will not allow copypaste, but also may be solution:

HTML

```
<span class='eml'>resu</span>@domain.com​
```

CSS:

```
.eml {
    direction:rtl;
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HmZew/1/

it should be shown correct even if  javascript is off